# Sort one column in ascending (alphabetically) but on the values of the other column in descending order? Look at the expected output carefully

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a dataframe like this:

```
name     value
ray     20
sun     20
mom     10
ate     10
pea      7
kite     6
dance    5
```

I want to arrange this like:

```
ray 20
sun 20
ate 10
mom 10
pea 7
kite 6
dance 5
```

Comment: @jezrael, look at this.

Comment: You can just use `df.sort_values(['value','name'], ascending=[False,True])` but please follow the guidelines to ask questions properly and nicely https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 17):

It's pretty straightforward: pass both columns and their ascending flags to `sort_values`:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'name': ['ray', 'sun', 'mom', 'ate', 'pea', 'kite', 'dance'],
    'value': [20, 20, 10, 10, 7, 6, 5]
})

df.sort_values(by=['value', 'name'], ascending=[False, True])
#    name  value
# 0  ray   20
# 1  sun   20
# 3  ate   10
# 2  mom   10
# 4  pea    7
# 5  kite   6
# 6  dance  5
```

Comment: Sorry I commented in the same second you posted :-) but I think you got the ascending part reversed.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I don't particularly prefer doing the below, but this is still another solution for this:

```
print(pd.DataFrame(sorted(df.values,key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True),columns=df.columns))
```

Output:

```
    name  value
0    sun     20
1    mom     20
2    ray     10
3    ate     10
4    pea      7
5   kite      6
6  dance      5
```